# Part of speech search with lucene

Tags: lucene, nlp, synonym, payload, part-of-speech

After many googling searchs I decided to post my problem here hoping that someone help me. What I want to achieve is to perform queries as follows:

```
q1: (adjective) "jumps" (preposition) // any adj followed by "jumps" followed by any prep.  
q2: (adjective:brown) "jumps" (preposition) // brown as adj. followed by "jumps" followed by any prep.  
q3: (adjective:brown) (verb:jumps) (preposition) // brown as adj followed by jumps as verb followed by any preposition.
```

In a more general form, what I want is

```
(POS[:specific_word]) (POS[:specific_word]) (POS[:specific_word])
```

For that, I have the text tagged as follows:

```
the|[pos:DT][lemma:the] quick|[pos:JJ][lemma:quick] brown|[pos:JJ][lemma:brown] fox|[pos:NN][lemma:fox] jumps|[pos:NNS][lemma:jump] over|[pos:IN][lemma:over] the|[pos:DT][lemma:the] lazy|[pos:JJ][lemma:lazy] dog|[pos:NN][lemma:dog]
```

The first thing I thought was to index extra info of each term as payload and using PayloadNearQuery after in order to access to the payload of each span. The problem is that PayloadNearQuery match the terms first and then access its payload, so none of the 3 above queries will work. (correct me if I'm wrong)

The second thing I thought was to index extra info as synonyms of the term but, this way, the second query won't work since I can't ask if the first term is an adj and the specific word "brown" simultaneously.

Any way to address this problem, suggestions, etc. will be appreciated.